# Как запустить GTA SAMP 0.3.7 сервер через Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Столкнулся с проблемой такой. Мне требуется сделать так, что бы в коде Python можно было запустить отдельно взятый сервер SAMP, не заходя в клиент SAMP. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: запустить в смысле сам сервер или зайти на сервер?

Comment: Ну как, что бы можно было сразу играть там)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам предварительно нужно просмотреть какие пакеты и куда отправляет SAMP (с помощью TCPView, например), после чего вы можете отправлять эти пакеты, эмилурия вход в SAMP, с помощью `requests` или любой другой библиотеки для работы с http-запросами.

Comment: думаю не это имелось ввиду